# Is there a way to use WebGL tensorflow backend with Mali T720 (Samsung Tab E)?

Tags: tensorflow, webgl, tensorflow.js

Currently, the initialization of WebGL backend in tfjs fails on Mali T720 with the error message `GL context does not support color renderable floats`.

Looks like this is due to lack of support of the extension `EXT_color_buffer_float`, based on this thread - https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/502

Running on the CPU is painfully slow - 30sec per frame even on small networks. Is there a way to bypass the extension limitation so that tensorflow can use the GPU?

Comment: I doubt it. If the GPU doesn't support `EXT_color_buffer_float` then it's arguably incapable of being used the way tensorflow needs it to be used. [A Mali-T820 does have those capabilities but a T720 does not](https://opengles.gpuinfo.org/)